# How to set alarm based on date and time saved in database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, events, android-alarms

I am using a custom event to store data in the database, I have subject, description, date, and time. Is it possible to set an alarm based on the date and time inserted in the database? I am trying to retrieve all of dates and time to match up on the current day and exact time. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Q: `Is it possible to set an alarm based on the date and time inserted in the database?` A: **Yes, it is**.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get date from db.

```
String dateTime = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_INDEX));
```

This, returns a string, parse it and reformat to your local format and time zone:

```
DateFormat yourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
date = yourDateFormat.parse(dateTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Parsing date time failed", e);
}
```

now set a alarm using below code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0)
{
//The set Date/Time already passed
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Date/Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: I want to just set up a basic alarm that only triggers when the user is in the app and a due date from my sqlite database is reached.  In that case, there is no need for an AlarmManager correct?  Apparently all that is needed is use of a Handler with Timer and Thread.  Yet I don't see any Handler examples on stackoverflow.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by using BroadcastReceiver class in android. You must search and read it.